# Putting References in the Footline [NOT footnote] of Beamer

Tags: beamer

I've made several changes in a `Warsaw` theme. 
Please take a look at my MWE:

```
%%%%%Packages%%%%%%%


\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%Theme&Colors%%%%%%%


\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
\definecolor{Navyblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} 

\definecolor{crimson}{rgb}{0.86, 0.08, 0.24}
\usecolortheme[named=Navyblue]{structure}


%%%%%Colors of Parts%%%%%%%



\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=Navyblue,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=black,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=Navyblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=Navyblue,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=white,fg=black}



%%%%%Footline%%%%%%%



\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{fg=white,bg=Navyblue}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{footlinecolor}
{}
    \hspace{0.3cm}%
    \scriptsize{\hfill {\tiny \insertframenumber\,\textbf{/}\,\inserttotalframenumber}}
    \hfill

  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Synthesis of the Elusive Branched Fluoro-Oligogermane \ce{(Ph3Ge)3GeF}}
\author{Ardalan}
\institute{}
\date{\begin{scriptsize}
November 8, 2019
\end{scriptsize}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame} [plain]
\titlepage

\end{frame}



\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Germanium Catenates}
\begin{frame}[t]{\ce{Ge-F} Containing Compounds} \vspace{20pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item There are 134 compounds in total that contain \ce{Ge-F} bond.

\begin{itemize}
\item Only one crystallographically characterized germanium-fluorine compound having unsupported \ce{Ge-Ge} bonds.
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
\vspace{30pt}








\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

---

I used to put the refences in each slide using:

```
%\blfootnote{{\tiny{\textit{\textbf{J. Am. Chem. Soc.}} 2010,  132, 38}}}
    %for footnote solution #1

    %\footnotetext{\textit{\textbf{J. Am. Chem. Soc.}} 2010,  132, 38}
```

But now I want to put them in the actual footline of each slide, like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean like a `\blfootnote` equivalent? Like a `\blfootline{…}` command?

Comment: @DavidPurton Sorry I didn't get what you said but the answer below is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can naturally add them, but this is a rather unusual place - there is not much space there. I'm not sure if is worth to develop an interface.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%Theme&Colors%%%%%%%


\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
\definecolor{Navyblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667}

\definecolor{crimson}{rgb}{0.86, 0.08, 0.24}
\usecolortheme[named=Navyblue]{structure}


%%%%%Colors of Parts%%%%%%%



\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=Navyblue,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=black,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=Navyblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=Navyblue,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=white,fg=black}



%%%%%Footline%%%%%%%



\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{fg=white,bg=Navyblue}
\newcommand\insertreferences{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{footlinecolor}
{}
    \hspace{0.3cm}%
    \scriptsize{\insertreferences\hfill {\tiny \insertframenumber\,\textbf{/}\,\inserttotalframenumber}}
    \hfill

  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Synthesis of the Elusive Branched Fluoro-Oligogermane \ce{(Ph3Ge)3GeF}}
\author{Ardalan}
\institute{}
\date{\begin{scriptsize}
November 8, 2019
\end{scriptsize}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame} [plain]
\titlepage

\end{frame}



\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Germanium Catenates}

\renewcommand\insertreferences{{\tiny\color{red}References: blblblb}}

\begin{frame}[t]{\ce{Ge-F} Containing Compounds} \vspace{20pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item There are 134 compounds in total that contain \ce{Ge-F} bond.

\begin{itemize}
\item Only one crystallographically characterized germanium-fluorine compound having unsupported \ce{Ge-Ge} bonds.
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
\vspace{30pt}


\end{frame}

\renewcommand\insertreferences{}

\begin{frame}{Another Frame}
blblbl
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I wanted. I noticed you've get to add them before each frame. It's working just fine.